# I’ve raised a baby magpie and wanting to release it back into the wild

Tags: feeding, eating, birds

I found a young baby magpie that had been pushed out of the nest way too early since it was still developing feathers. So I took it in and raised it but now I have had it for three weeks and I want to release it back into the wild. I am wondering will they be alright. I have tried to get other magpies that I believe are the parents but I’m not sure to come and feed it so I don’t have to. Though I let the baby magpie sit on a tree near the nest that it fell out of one day and another magpie came up to it to feed it, however the baby magpie didn’t take the food. I wonder why? So now I have let it stay in the house because it keeps coming back and I don’t know what to do. Just wondering what I should do and if anyone else has experienced this?

Comment: I would strongly recommend consulting with your local wildlife rescue agencies (which should have been the first step when you found the bird). They can recommend the correct steps, or take the bird into a sanctuary if it is unable to be released back to the wild.

Answer (score 3):

This [german website](https://wp.wildvogelhilfe.org/vogelwissen/die-aufzucht/auswilderung-von-jungvoegeln/) (with a lots of pictures) states, that it needs an outdoor enclosure to make the birds comfortable with the outside weather, noise and other conditions.

Magpies are "Nesthocker", which is the german term for animals born blind and without fur/feathers. This birds need to live in the enclosure to learn in a safe environment how to find food. Magpies eat everything, from insects, worms, seeds, over old meat and leftovers to fruits and berries.

So your task now is, to show the bird as much sources for food as possible ([how to feed magpies and other crows](https://wp.wildvogelhilfe.org/vogelwissen/die-aufzucht/aufzucht-bestimmter-vogelarten/rabenvoegel-aufziehen/)) and give it the chance to search for it itself ("hide it" in the enclosure). Then, when you are satisfied, you choose a time of good weather period, feed the bird a big meal and open the doors of the enclosure. Then comes a time when the Magpie will come and go as it likes, and soon it will stay longer and longer away. Some future day it will come only for visits, i.e. to get food in cold winter or similar.

Magpies are very intelligent birds. So I assume it will remember your place as safe spot and secure food source. But this also is a challenge, because "domesticated" Magpies without "respect" against humans, mostly do not live long. So you need also to cut your contact at the mare minimum, and let it go not before it does not search contact to humans anymore. More information about this part you will find [here](https://wp.wildvogelhilfe.org/vogelwissen/die-aufzucht/aufzucht-bestimmter-vogelarten/rabenvoegel-aufziehen/auswilderung-junger-rabenvoegel/).